# attach_image parameter in Visual Composer / WPBakery allowing multiple images to be selected

Tags: php, visual-composer, wpbakery

I'm building out a custom element which is just a single image. Here's how I've defined the parameters:

```
'params' => array(

    array(
        'type' => 'attach_image',
        'heading' => esc_html__("Image"),
        'param_name' => 'image',
        'value' => esc_html__(''),
        'admin_label' => false,
        'weight' => 0,
    )

}
```

According to the [documentation](https://kb.wpbakery.com/docs/inner-api/vc_map/), `attach_image` is used for `Single image selection`. However, in the admin side, I'm able to choose more than one image:

[image]

Above, I've added a yellow bg image, but get the option to add another - I only want one to be allowed (which is what I thought `attach_image` does).

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, This option should't add new one. It will change your previous image.